# How can I change the resize mode in the back end in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, resize

I have set the initial resize mode of the window to be "NoResize" as shown below.

```
<Widnow ... WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize">
```

I want to change the resize mode to "CanResizeWithGrip" after this button is clicked.

```
<Button x:Name="btnResize" Content="Click Me!" Click="BtnResize_Click"/>
```

And this is my event.

```
private void BtnResize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void BtnResize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.CanResizeWithGrip;
}
```